# How to extract a text using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

What is the problem with my code

```
var str = "[356] Hello World";
var patt = new RegExp("(?!\[)\d+(?<!\])","");
var result = patt.exec(str);
```

**Result Should Be = 356**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't do negative lookbehinds in Javascript.

---

Something like this should work:

```
var str = '[356] Hello World',
    patt = /\[(\d+)\]/,
    result = patt.exec(str)[1];
```

This creates a matching group and selects the match with `[1]`.

Comment: Are there another way to extract "356"

Answer (score 1):

[Lookbehinds are not supported in JavaScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

You can instead try using capturing subpatterns.

```
var str = "[356] Hello World";
var match = str.match(/\[(\d+)\]/);
var result = match ? match[1] : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have pointed out, you have the wrong syntax for lookarounds.

- `(?!regex)` is a negative lookahead, but you're using it as a positive lookbehind.
- `(?<!regex)` is a negative lookbehind, but you're using it as a positive lookahead.

Since lookbehinds aren't supported in JS, **Thai**'s and **lonesomeday**'s answers are the way to go. In a language that did support them, you'd want this:

```
/(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])/
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why Thai's and not mine?

Comment: @lonesomeday: Did you edit yours? Maybe I just didn't read it right the first time. Sorry about that. See edit. One of your +1s is fom me, too.

Comment: It's odd -- I thought I saw you recommending my answer earlier, and then it seemed you had edited and removed it, and I was curious why! Overactive imagination.

Comment: @lonesomeday - Now I remember. I had two windows open. Sorry, my fault.